# NIST SP 800-90A DRBG, incorrect reult following algorithm, correct result rearranging algorithm steps?

Tags: hash, random, nist

I've been starring at this issue for about three days now, and think I need a second set of eyes on the problem. I'm implementing NIST's `HASH_DRBG` from [SP 800-90A Rev. 1, June 2015](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-90Ar1.pdf) (its the latest doc according to [NIST Special Publications page](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html)). The test vectors are located at [CAVP Testing: Random Number Generators](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/random-number-generation.html).

The problem I am having is I cannot arrive at the test vector result ***if*** I follow the algorithm as published. ***If*** I move one step down a few slots, then I can arrive at the correct result. Its very unusual, and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

The algorithm I am having problem with it ***Hash_DRBG_Generate Process***. Here's the algorithm as a screen capture from section 10.1.1.4 around page 50:

[image]

Step 3, ***Hashgen***, produces the pseduo-random bits for the caller. Steps 4-6 then update state for the next call to generate.

***If*** I execute the algorithm exactly as specified, then I return the following bit string to the caller, which is incorrect. Effectively, it uses *Current V*.

```
6C58FE76D644750EA5BE880BB1BDD2D54C98139D70BA0F7CA8637EB2527F8BFD223DEB9187976E87
91B706804FB28534D13EC4818FB59DB430C9F04F55AA8549EAD53B39624DAD6CFDAAD99412B8AEB0
```

***If*** I move Step 3 between Step 6 and Step 7, then I can arrive at the correct result. Effectively, it uses *Next V*.

```
56f33d4fdbb9a5b64d26234497e9dcb87798c68d08f7c41199d4bddf97ebbf6cb5550e5d149ff4d5
bd0f05f25a6988c17436396227184af84a564335658e2f8572bea333eee2abff22ffa6de3e22aca2
```

My questions are pretty crummy:

1. Am am parsing things incorrectly or doing something obviously wrong?
2. Why do I need to move Step 3 down to Step 6 and Step 7?
3. If I have to choose, should I select (a) correct algorithm and incorrect result, or (b) incorrect algorithm and correct result?

---

Here's the test vector I'm working from. Its the first test vector (`COUNT 0`) using SHA1 with *no* predictive resistance. The problem occurs at ***GENERATE (FIRST CALL)***. The ***`V`*** value shown, `1658...ed56b`, is the value after Steps 4-6 have executed. However, V does not take that value until after Step 3, ***Hashgen***, has executed.

```
[SHA-1]
[PredictionResistance = False]
[EntropyInputLen = 128]
[NonceLen = 64]
[PersonalizationStringLen = 0]
[AdditionalInputLen = 0]
[ReturnedBitsLen = 640]

COUNT = 0
EntropyInput = 1610b828ccd27de08ceea032a20e9208
Nonce = 492cf1709242f6b5
PersonalizationString = 
** INSTANTIATE:
    V = 9e8301725d5f133b4ab7d329fd2f87ae5f89d96a9dd7e2b98beee1c707b8c3fe412d1125b58bae5dc08a11dac3be4a3147347160fef218
    C = e5e12450450efe5fdc777c95b8c23c938fcd592e2d788f12461936e4a16131b1f2d11ce7f0159ee1e635e62f3df8bda4fea077ad5f9d06
    reseed counter = 1
EntropyInputReseed = 72d28c908edaf9a4d1e526d8f2ded544
AdditionalInputReseed = 
** RESEED:
    V = 745c659f2944829ca6e209c8ca2dddecf9f1861383e34e94007a3a51b8444fd5ae738e7d9c0d5e69aa97ee16c49cfd2432eb32ba5738fa
    C = a1fc40009357a024d878818cf6f979a88d4cc5d760b308ae1a5b9f067972e6f7cf92ddb129a8d3c1bb0005bcf3f8871fd65e794f1990b7
    reseed counter = 1
AdditionalInput = 
** GENERATE (FIRST CALL):
    V = 1658a59fbc9c22c17f5a8b55c1275795873e4beae49657421ad5d95831b736cd7e066c738bcbb343933c411c7c17917593c03a77bed56b
    C = a1fc40009357a024d878818cf6f979a88d4cc5d760b308ae1a5b9f067972e6f7cf92ddb129a8d3c1bb0005bcf3f8871fd65e794f1990b7
    reseed counter = 2
AdditionalInput = 
ReturnedBits = 56f33d4fdbb9a5b64d26234497e9dcb87798c68d08f7c41199d4bddf97ebbf6cb5550e5d149ff4d5bd0f05f25a6988c17436396227184af84a564335658e2f8572bea333eee2abff22ffa6de3e22aca2
** GENERATE (SECOND CALL):
    V = b854e5a04ff3c2e657d30ce2b820d13e148b11c245495ff03531785eab2a1dc54d994a5597b15c5b10001f49606c88b4ff0d61acb61820
    C = a1fc40009357a024d878818cf6f979a88d4cc5d760b308ae1a5b9f067972e6f7cf92ddb129a8d3c1bb0005bcf3f8871fd65e794f1990b7
    reseed counter = 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this mystery can be found in another NIST document, [The 
NIST SP 800-90A Deterministic Random Bit Generator Validation System (DRBGVS)](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/drbg/DRBGVS.pdf), p.4:

[image]

The ***Generate random bits, do not print*** is the *`6C58...AEB0`* bit string. The second one, ***Generate random bits, print out*** is the *`56f3...aca2`* bit string.

Comment: Hey jww. Glad you got it solved, although I think the solution is pretty specific to your problem. Anyway, you should be able to accept your own answer by now. I'll vote it up for the simple reason that hey, it may still help someone and you took the time to report back. (Currently it was bumped to the front page by the Community process because no answer has been accepted.)